# Refusal of a UK Standard Visitor Visa (no economic ties)

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I have applied for my mother to visit me and my children in the UK for six months and the application has been refused.

**The decision**

> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not
>   satisfied that you meet the requirement of paragraph(S) 4.2, of
>   Appendix V: Immigration rules for visitors becuase;
>
> You state you will visit your daughter a British citizen, in the UK
>   for six months. You have provided a letter from your sponsor stating
>   that you are her 'biological mother', however  you have not provided
>   any evidence you are related as claimed and when your sponsor applied
>   for entry clearance in November 2004 she stated that her mother was
>   HAJIA GRACE JONES.
>
> I acknowledge your sponsor proposes to pay for your visit, however, it
>   is the circumstances of the applicant that remain paramount when
>   assessing your application. You have provided no evidence regarding
>   youur own circumstances in NIGERIA such as evidence of income, savings
>   property or other assets. It is your responsibility to demonstrate
>   that if granted entry clearance, you will comply with the terms of
>   your visa and have the intention to leave. I consider you have failed
>   to demonstrate economic ties in Nigeria.
>
> I acknowledge you have previously travelled to the UK however this was
>   in November 2011, over four years and I am required to assess your
>   circumstances as demonstrated in your current application.
>
> The above facts combined means I am not satisfied that your
>   circumstances are as claimed. I am therefore not satisfied that you
>   are a genuine visitor and will leave the UK at the end of your visit.
>   Your application has been refused under paragraph V4.2 (a)and (c).
>
> Future applications Any future UK applications you make will be
>   considered on their individual merits, however you are likely to be
>   refused unless:
>
> - Your personal circumstances change significantly between now and your next application
> - you provide compelling new evidence with your next application
>
> in relation to this decision there is no right of appeal or right to
>   administrative review.

**Please Note**
My mother is 68 years of age and was self employed but retired now. Her finances come from us her children abroad which was stated in the application but provided her bank statement with approximately £1000 equivalent savings. She does not have any dependants back home but often takes care of her grandchildren who visit her frequently. 
An error was made in regards to her origin, stating NIGERIA instead of Ghana and the Surname Jones was our dads surname which she used previously. My mum travelled to the UK in 2011 with the same passport she submitted bearing the same surname (Adam) which is her dads surname.

My question is that the refusal was given to her today and I want to reapply again hopefully tomorrow however, I do want to address the concerns raised in the refusal letter which I stated earlier

Comment: Take heed, you will not adequately address the ECO's concerns by tomorrow, next week, next month or possibly even this year. But I will start the process of reopening your question.

Comment: Thank you Gayot Fow. I believe I have other evidence to attach to the new application such as proof of owning a property, her bank statement, photographs of my mother and my children both in the UK and in Ghana, birth certificate to proof she is my biological mother. Evidence that she returned to the UK when she was previously granted visa to visit us. And evidence of close ties with Ghana such as letter from the Imam stating she provides marriage counselling at the local mosque and actively involved in the day to day activities of the mosque. The errors re Nigeria instead of GHANA.

Comment: @Meldah You should put additional information into your question - comments can be overlooked, and may be deleted, while the question remains

Comment: Suggesting to close this as a dupe since the refusal formula is the same and the gist is identic, even if student and 68 y.o. mom are of course different applicants.

Answer (score -3):

[Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) says

*(a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit; and
(c) is genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor routes (these are listed in Appendices 3, 4 and 5); and*

- I think you should provide evidence that she is your mother, something mention that explicitly.
- You should provide a return ticket to comply with point "a"
- If you say that she has no body back home, so they might be thinking the same, if she has no body back home then she will remain in the UK. So, you have to provide some supporting documents to explain why she will be back home and will not remain in the UK to handle point "c"

Comment: Thank you Ahmed Hashim for your valuable answer. In regards to the evidences, I have birth certificate, childhood photographs, photographs of her visit to the UK with myself and my children, photo's of us in Hajj together etc. With regards to purchasing a ticket, I am unsure as they state clearly not to purchase any tickets prior to them granting a visa. Again I did not state that she did not have anyone back home but mentioned that she did not have any dependants because all her children are grown ups. I intend to say that she has grand children who visit her regularly and spend the weekends.

Comment: **Buying a return ticket is not how you prove you will leave at the end of your visit.** Simply having a ticket does not guarantee that you will use it. If you do this, you only prove that you did not read and understand the guidance, and risk another refusal.

Comment: not an answer for the refusal reasons mentioned above:relationship evidence,evidence of (income,property or other assets),staggering economic ties